# Dlls unloading order in Unix and Windows

Tags: dll, shared-libraries

I have 2 dlls: A and B.

From a code in dll A, I am loading dynamically the dll B (using dlopen on Unix and LoadLibrary on Windows). Is it guaranteed that B will be **unloaded** before A?

Is there any difference between Unix and Windows behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no guarantee as to which DLL will be unloaded first (Unix and WIndows do not differ on this point).